# CKEditor Custom Toolbar Configuration

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've looked through several questions in this forum and the CKEditor site about this topic, but nothing's helped so far.  First of all, I'm running CKEditor 4.3.2 on a SharePoint 2010 site, using inline editors within a jQuery UI modal dialog.  Adding CKEditor to the dialog was painless, but I can't say the same for setting up a slimmer toolbar.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. slimConfig.js

   ```
   CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
       config.toolbar = [
           {name: "basicstyles", items: ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "Subscript", "Superscript", "-", "RemoveFormat"]},
           {name: "paragraph", items: ["NumberedList", "BulletedList"]}
       ];
   }
   ```
2. Source JavaScript

   ```
   setToolbar("notes");
   setToolbar("access");
   //. . .[several other fields]. . .

   function setToolbar(divName) {
       CKEDITOR.replace(divName, {customConfig: "/customConfigs/slimConfig.js"});
   }
   ```

Additionally, I've set up the target fields as divs using `contenteditable` set to true, like this:

```
<div id="notes" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

The script seems to run well until it hits an exception on ckeditor.js line 308, where the error text is "The editor instance  is already attached to the provided element."  After a few more steps, it returns to the same area on line 308, at which point I get a terminal exception with the message, "Exception thrown and not caught."

I believe I have everything set up properly right now, but don't know what to make of this error.  Does anyone have experience with getting customized toolbars set up?

Answer (score 1):

By default CKEditor replaces all elements of `contenteditable="true"` with inline editors. So when you try to replace it once again, it will throw an error because it doesn't make sense.

If you want to take a full control over your editors, set [CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-cfg-disableAutoInline) to `false` and take care of all instances manually. Of course, you can always find your instance in `CKEDITOR.instances` object and call `editor.destroy()` if you want to.

See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, oleq! Unfortunately, I'm very new to CKEDITOR, and I didn't have much luck even with the documentation. I added the CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline=true line just above the setToolbar calls, and added CKEDITOR.inline(divName); as the first line within setToolbar(). Is that the right direction? Can you provide an example?